# Update-heavy table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

after profiling my server I found out that updating a datetime-column of a row in a table takes about 5ms, since I do this about 150 times per second, it is a major performance issue. The column is not indexed and the storage engine is InnoDB. The table just has 500 entries and the update looks like this (userId is the primary key):

```
UPDATE users SET lastactive = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE userId = 23;
```

I tried to solve it the following ways:

1. I tried to use the storage engine MEMORY since the data is not so important. I was planning to batch write its contents to the users table every 1 minute. Seems like MEMORY storage engine also takes 5ms for one update.
2. I tried to use MyISAM. Still 5ms per update.
3. I tried to batch the update queries. still 5ms per query.

Why do updates seem to take 5ms generally? Is there a way to do faster updates is MySQL? I need something like a HashMap in Java. Doesnt even need to be 100% durable, since I can sync it with the user table periodically and if data is lost occasionally, I dont care.

How would you solve that problem? By the way I use a MySQL instance on Google Cloud Compute with replication active.

Comment: does `userId` column have an index on it?

Comment: `userId` should probably be a `PRIMARY KEY` in the table.

Comment: as I said, userId is the Primary key

Comment: The MySQL engine needs to parse the SQL statement, Optimize the SQL query, check privileges, open the table if you have privileges for that table (Random disk I/O if table is not open in cache),and finally update the table (some disk I/O required) all this take some time... .you could try to batch the updates in a transaction if your are using InnoDB

Comment: In general your query should take around 1 ms even with 10000 records, unless, there are foreign key associations affected, triggers running before/after update, poorly configured database `(my.cf)`, or logging levels are set to a high verbosity. What is the output of `EXPLAIN UPDATE users SET lastactive = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE userId = 23;` Also how many columns does the table have?

Comment: there are like 40 columns

Comment: id = 1,
select_type = SIMPLE,
table = dealers_employees,
type = range,
possible_keys = PRIMARY,
key = PRIMARY,
key_len = 4,
ref = const,
rows = 1,
Extra = Using where

Comment: Maybe its a time of response between you and server? Try to make about 10 updates in one query and look how much time it needs.

Comment: it isnt the server response time since I use the mysql profiling mode and this does only count the internal time, but I think I will do this.. it seems to work: INSERT INTO dealers_employees (dealerEmployeeId,dealerEmployeeLastActive) VALUES (446, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),(158, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),(308, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),(309, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dealerEmployeeLastActive=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;